# Webots world disintegration

Tags: webots

I had a problem with my Webots world. If I start the simulation the object flies away from the ground.
I got the following warning message:

**WARNING: The current physics step could not be computed correctly. Your world may be too complex. If this problem persists, try simplifying your bounding object(s), reducing the number of joints, or reducing WorldInfo.basicTimeStep.**

I tried to reducing the WorldInfo.basicTimeStep but don't work, reducing the world, but I can't better than that, so I'm clueless. Every object has Physics with mass = 1.

Here's a picture with the Worldinfo:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v8GE.jpg)

[World](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fEFE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It could related to objects colliding with each other at the initial position. You should try to simplify your world file (e.g., remove objects one by one) until it doesn't explode anymore to understand which part is causing the problem. Then, you will be able to re-add the objects, taking are of the problematic ones.