# Fixing objects in their place in webots

Tags: webots

I'm trying to put two different solid objects on a desk in webots and move them later. They are quiet similar but not the same. While one of the objects is nicely in its position, the other object is not stable and moves strangely around its position (I've put it both close to and far from the stable object but the result is the same).

Does anyone know how I can make the second object also standing still on its position?

Additional info: for each object, I have used its own geometry to bounded it, as following:

```
geometry DEF object1 IndexedFaceSet{
...
}

 boundingObject USE object1
```

The physic also is defined as following:

```
physics Physics {
      density -1
      mass 0.3
    }
```

P.s. I believe my problem is different than [Webots world disintegration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64645982/webots-world-disintegration), since I don't get any warning and the object is not flying but moves around its position. I also removed the stable object, but the second object (alone in the world) did not get stable.

Comment: Try to approximate the bounding object with a primitive shape (e.g. box, sphere, cylinder, or similar). Avoid using meshes as the bounding object (it is hard to calculate collisions and it makes the simulation unstable).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I set physics to null and used supervisor to control the environment...